# How to parse xml in windows-1251 coding?

Tags: android

I try to parse web resource that give data in ni utf format, but when I start parsing I get:

```
12-08 11:30:44.097: E/Reader(670): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Error parsing document. (position:line -1, column -1) caused by: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 10, column 15: not well-formed (invalid token)
12-08 11:30:44.097: E/Reader(670):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser$ByteDocument.flush(ExpatPullParser.java:958)
12-08 11:30:44.097: E/Reader(670):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser$Document.pump(ExpatPullParser.java:769)
12-08 11:30:44.097: E/Reader(670):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser$Document.dequeue(ExpatPullParser.java:813)
12-08 11:30:44.097: E/Reader(670):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser.next(ExpatPullParser.java:302)
12-08 11:30:44.097: E/Reader(670):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser.nextTag(ExpatPullParser.java:338)
12-08 11:30:44.097: E/Reader(670):  at com.home.network.RssParser.parseSax(RssParser.java:78)
```

I set UTF-8 parameter in my parser but it doesn't help:

```
        List<Feed> feeds = new ArrayList<Feed>();
try {
    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
    parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
    parser.setInput(is, "UTF-8");
//          parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser., state)
    parser.nextTag();
    feeds = readFeed(parser);
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    Log.e("Reader", "Parse exception", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Reader", "Parse exception", e);
} finally {
```

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to transfer null as the second param:

```
parser.setInput(is, null);
```

in this case the parser will try to autodetect encoding of content.